# How to insert a line break after every 28 characters without breaking words, IN T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I Need help to insert a line break after every 28 characters, but if its in the middle of a word its should go to the next space and make the break, my code is now a stuff function where i concatenate multiple records

```
STUFF((
    SELECT 
    new_maincatgoriesname
    FROM new_subcatagories
    WHERE new_subcatagories.new_subcatagoriesid  in (select [new_subactivitys] from new_activityassigment where new_assigndomain = new_sessionactivitydefinitionid)
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,1,'')
```

Comment: So you want a lline to be a maximum of 28 chars or 28 chars + the remaining characters of a word before the next line? Some sample data and expected results would help, along with your SQL Server version.

Comment: I would personally say that SQL Server is therefore not likely to be the right tool for doing this. Though you could, it would probably require iteration, which isn't something SQL is good at, and T-SQL's string manipulation tools is rudimentaal at best. Doing this in the application would likely be a far better place.

Comment: Has your research included searching for [`[tsql] split string maximum length`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btsql%5D+split+string+maximum+length)? What do you need that those answers don't provide?

Comment: If this is a regular task run frequently in your system you may wish to invest into creating a [custom CLR aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-user-defined-aggregate-invoking-functions?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a procedural, not a set-based approach for that kind of text manipulation.  TSQL isn't the best at that sort of thing, but it can be done.  EG

```
create or alter function SplitLines(@val nvarchar(max), @lineLen int)
returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin
/*
  select dbo.splitLines('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.', 15)
*/
  declare @i int = 0
  declare @curLen int = 0;
  declare @rv nvarchar(max) = '';
  

  while @i <= len(@val)
  begin
    
    declare @c nvarchar(1) = substring(@val,@i,1)
    set @curlen = @curlen + 1

    set @rv = @rv + @c
    if @curlen >= @lineLen
    begin
      if @c = N' '
      begin
        set @rv = @rv + char(10)
        set @curlen = 0
      end
    end
    
    set @i = @i + 1
  end
  return @rv
end
```

the test code outputs

```
The quick brown 
fox jumped over 
the lazy dog.

(1 row affected)
```